# Remove mobile number from a string of text in power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a column that contains case details.

How do I remove the mobile number from the string of text in PowerBI?

Constraint:
Not able to use R or python.

I have not been able to find a solution.

Sample Data

| Ref | Details |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mary called on 24.6.2023 to check on her application. Please call her back at 65283638. She wants this resolved in 3 days. |
| 2 | Date of call: 23.5.2023 Caller Name: Jane Contact: 62535353 She wants a callback. |

Comment: You wants to remove the mobile number? or extract the number in new column? 
Text the whole string except mobile number always same?

Comment: Added the sample data

Comment: Is there any specific format in Mobile number? I can see the texts are random. You need a fix structure either in the mobile number on in the text. Other wise you can not make it dynamic.

Comment: Mobile number is always 8-digit long. No special characters in between.

Comment: Any word in the string can be 8 character in length, so it will not work. Any other logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write following M code to achieve this.
Split column text and compare each word does not contain 'phone number' and 'phone number with dot' at the end then combine words

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Ashok\Power BI\Stack Overflow\Data_23jun23.xlsx"), null, true),
    Data_Sheet = Source{[Item="Data",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Data_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Ref", Int64.Type}, {"Details", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Select(Text.Split([Details], " "), each not(

(Text.Length(_)=8) and (Text.Contains(_, "1") or Text.Contains(_, "2") or Text.Contains(_, "3")

or Text.Contains(_, "4") or Text.Contains(_, "5") or Text.Contains(_, "6") or Text.Contains(_, "7") or Text.Contains(_, "8") or Text.Contains(_, "9") or Text.Contains(_, "0") )
or (Text.Length(_)=9 and Text.End(_,1) = ".") and (Text.Contains(_, "1") or Text.Contains(_, "2") or Text.Contains(_, "3")
or Text.Contains(_, "4") or Text.Contains(_, "5") or Text.Contains(_, "6") or Text.Contains(_, "7") or Text.Contains(_, "8")
or Text.Contains(_, "9") or Text.Contains(_, "0") 
))), " "))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Comment: But if I have 1000 cases, that column will have 10,000 different phone numbers, split into different rows. Is there a more efficient way to remove all the phone numbers?

Comment: Please paste your sample data

Comment: Ok added the sample data

Comment: Updated my answer. If this solves your issue, accept answer and upvote